# Where do i download XNA? (in visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

I was looking to start learning XNA and make games with it.When i tried looking online for videos and websites it didn't work, I saw videos about XNA but i didn't download button.

Comment: Asking for downloads/locations is explicitly OFF-TOPIC

Comment: probably worth noting that XNA is considered dead.  Microsoft isn't supporting it - and hasn't for a few years

Comment: I think you're looking for monogame

Comment: @Jonesopolis Microsoft stops releasing new versions of it, but its product lifecycle does not yet end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is quite lazy

Answer (score 1):

You can still download from links like this

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714